# Why am i getting a triggered breakpoint?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to make my own vector class, i think i have implemented everything correct but i get this error saying "main.exe has triggered a breakpoint". The program runs fine untill it goes out of scope then my destructor throws this exception, i think there is something wrong with the capacity container that i create.

```
template<typename A>
inline void myVector<A>::capacityChange(int size)
{
if (size <= _capacity)
{
    return;
}
A * newVector = new A[size]; // Skapar ett nytt vector för det nya capacitet

//kopierar allt i det förra array till den nya
for ( int i = 0; i < _capacity; i++)
{
    newVector[i] = _data[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    std::cout << i << ": " << newVector[i] << std::endl;
}


_capacity = size;

delete[] _data;

_data = newVector;

}
```

Comment: I'm curious what `test.vectorCapacity()` and `test.size()` were. And even though I don't see it causing a problem in this exact code, you should read about the Rule of Three or Rule of Five.

Comment: I will read about it, capacity and size is just the two variables i am using for my vector to manage memory.

Comment: Why did you remove the part of the code that actually contains the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be here:

```
template<typename A>
inline myVector<A>::myVector(const size_t &size, const A &value):   
           _size(size), _capacity(2 * size)
{
   _data = new A[size]();
```

In this constructor you've set `_capacity` to `2*size`, but you've only allocated an array of `size` objects.  That means that later, when your `main()` function calls `push_back()`, it will happily write past the end of your `_data` array before finally reallocating to a larger `_data` array; by that time your heap has been corrupted, which is why your `delete` call crashes later on (your writes-past-the-end-of-the-array probably overwrote some of the heap's metadata that it relies on to work correctly)

Comment: I understand, the array size still can be different as long as i have alocated for more of it... and later when the size becomes the same as the capacity it will reallocate for a larger array. Thank you sir!